# CHECK operation for two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have problems using a CHECK constraint. I have two tables

```
Users Table
userid | register_date 

Activity table
id | userid | activity_date
```

I need to put a constraint that disallows the insertion of an activity_date which is less than a register_date. I could do it with a CHECK constraint if they were in same table. But, how do you do it for two different tables? (also Oracle disallows sub-queries in a check constraint).

Is there any other way to perform this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a trigger:

```
create or replace trigger tr_activity
 before update or insert of activity_date on activity
 for each row
declare
   l_register_date users.register_date%type;
begin

   select register_date into l_register_date
     from users
    where id = :new.userid
          ;

   if :new.activity_date < l_register_date then
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Stop attempting the impossible');
   end if;

end tr_activity;
/
```

But, this seems a little strange; I would assume that you're only ever inserting the current date into the activity date, which means that the registration date will always be before the activity date, unless it's been updated prior. I would simply ensure that the activity date is never updated or inserted in your application code and use a default value in the table:

```
alter table activity modify activity_date default sysdate not null
```